# What is the de facto method for indicating price graphically?

Tags: gui-design, lists, mobile-application

I've seen the "$" sign used to indicate price range from $ (for low) to $$$ (for high) like below at TripAdvisor:

[image: Price indicators on TripAdvisor]

But is this well-understood by customers? What alternatives exist for indicating price visually without cluttering the UI with things like "Low", "Medium" and "High" which are difficult to discern when scrolling through a long list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the $ - $$$$ is a well defined pattern especially for restaurant pricing,  you can compare how this is used for say take away locations to how a similar filter would work for real estate where the actual dollar amount must be used.

So in short, if you are display the $$$$ for food/drink then it is a great option, if it is for something with more range like real estate then you should consider a different solution.

Comment: Bonus points if you use the currency sign based on user's location, so e.g., €€€€ for countries that use Euro. Foursquare does this and it's quite neat